# how to push to a cloned repo

Tags: git, github

I had been working on Github contributions. I have cloned a repo from someone and made changes. Then I tried to push it, it shows:

```
$ git push -u origin
remote: Permission to PronayTheVirus/LMSLibraryManagementSystem.git denied to SanjayRam07.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/PronayTheVirus/LMSLibraryManagementSystem.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Then I created a new branch and added all files by git add . and committed. Then, again I tried to push and it shows the same. What I need to do.

Expects:
To solve this issue and to push it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to contribute a merge request to another repo you'll need to fork it first:

1. Go to the project
2. [Fork the project to your own account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iOky.png)
3. [Clone your fork](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository)
4. Make changes
5. Push to your fork (make a new branch if needed)
6. Push to your fork
7. Create a pull request from your fork to the upstream repo

   (There will be a ['Contribute' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy59T.png) on your fork'ed repo page to simply this action)